# iOS: UIDynamics Push Behavior

Tags: ios, uikit-dynamics

I have created this little animation using `UIDynamics` - `Push Behavior`.

What I did was:

I created a simple `UIPushBehavior` like so:

```
self.pushBehavior = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.littleJumpy] mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
```

littleJumpy is just a `UIView` with size: `{20, 20}` that is added to the current view.

```
[animator addBehavior:self.pushBehavior];
```

Then afterward I would set the `magnitude` and then subsequently set `active = YES;`

The above is within a method.

It is working flawlessly.

At certain point in time I would set this push behavior's `active` state to `NO`.
And afterward I would set it again to `YES`.

The problem arises with this. I realized that once a push behavior's active state is set to `NO`, it cannot be revived again by setting it to `YES`.

As a result, I would need to alloc and configure a new push behavior and add it to the `animator` all over again.

What worries me is memory issue, if we need to `alloc` and `init` the push behavior again and again after setting its `active` state to `NO`.

For a few animations, it shouldn't hurt, but if someone wanted to create a continuous movement and during the period the behavior's `active` state is set to `NO` and cannot simply be revived by setting it again to `YES`, in which case a new `alloc` + `init` needs to be performed again and then added to the animator over and over again.

Is this the normal behavior or am I missing something here?

Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question.

But after months of experimenting, I came to a conclusion that once the `active` state is set to `NO`, I would have to re-`alloc` and re-`init` the behavior again, in order to re-use the behavior.

Other words, setting it again to `YES` from `NO` does not re-activate the behavior.